# How to convert 4K .mkv to .mp4 for YouTube

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion, video-conversion, youtube

I want to convert small clips of a 4K movie to .mp4 without losing quality so I can upload them to YouTube. Loading a whole movie into Premiere Pro and then cutting it at exact points is already a hassle because it doesn't support MKV. Even if you mod it to do, computer resources are limited for me to drag and cut this file around in the program.

FFmpeg seems to be the best option, but even if I did manage to convert (I did earlier on another machine back home), the results would come out sloppy, choppy, and grey because of the HDR to SDR conversing problems. Has anybody gotten this to work?

Comment: [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) may offer the ability to do so _(either `CTRL`+`R` or Media → Convert/Save...)_

Comment: YouTube accepts MKV.

Answer (score 0):

Want convert an **MKV file to MP4** try this step
I hope this work for you

1. Run "[VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) media player".
2. From main menu select "Media" > "Convert / Save...".
3. On "File" tab, click "Add..." button.
4. Choose you MKV file. After that, it should be added to the list. (Alternatively, you can drag&drop a file into the list.)
5. Click "Convert/Save" button.
6. Select Profile: "Video - H.264 + MP3 (MP4)".
7. Click on the icon button that has hint: "Edit selected profile".
8. On "Encapsulation" tab, leave "MP4/MOV" selected.
9. On "Video codec" tab, check both "Video" and "Keep original video track".
10. On "Audio codec" tab, similarly select both "Audio" and "Keep original audio track".
11. Click "Save" button.
12. In "Destination" selection, click "Browse" button to select directory and file name for you destination MP4 file.
13. Click "Start" button.
14. Observe progress bar in the main window as file is converted.

I found another way to quickly remux MKV to MP4 using [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/). This is a free and open source app intended mostly for video recording and streaming. The feature we need can be found in menu File > Remux Recordings.